# Communication between agents in AnyLogic

Tags: anylogic

I'm having trouble with linking my agents. I'm working with statecharts for agents 1 & 2:

When my **agent 1** (salesman) moves to his first client, the **agent 2 ** (Pedido_oro1) should turn red.
To achieve this, agent 1 sends a message to agent 2 with the action:

send("Order 1", Pedido_oro1);

However, when I try to run the model a problem appears "Pedido_oro1 cannot be resolved to a variable".

I have tried to link them so that the agent 2 gets the message and turns red but I can't.

I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Understand OOP in AnyLogic: https://anylogic.help/advanced/code/access.html#where-am-i-and-how-do-i-get-to